# How can i convert this statement to a SharePoint formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I'm new to SharePoint, I'm trying to convert the fallowing statement to a SharePoint formula any ideas.

```
if(num/1000 != 1){ return num;} else {num=0 ; return num;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out it was

```
=IF(num/1000<>1,num,num=0)
```